# How do I write a program in C# that reads a text file and outputs the total number of lines?

Tags: c#, counter

Studying a bachelor on Web Development, I've written some code which reads a text file and adds the lines to my console program,

I'm stuck on how I would write the code to count the amount of lines the text file outputs?

I've only been coding for a couple of months, any help would be great! (code is below)

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to reading from files");
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:/Temp/ReadingFromFile.txt");
    String line;
    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    tr.Close()
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Try this: `Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\ReadingFromFile.txt").Count());`

Comment: In general, you need a counter variable which gets incremented in every iteration of your loop. Also, you should use the `using` block with `StreamReader` as a best practice. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for details

Comment: @Enigmativity Where in the coding would I add this? I added the line of code after Console.WriteLine(line) is this appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to reading from files");
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\ReadingFromFile.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

As an alternative, you could do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to reading from files");
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\ReadingFromFile.txt"))
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\ReadingFromFile.txt").Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```